# Static IP address for my cloud function doesn't seem to work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc

I have a cloud function in GCP, it calls various APIs (some of them are in the same GCP project, others are external.) I want the function calls to have a static IP.

I followed this guide https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#route-egress-to-vpc

When I set up NAT, I reserved an IP address 34.XXX.XX..., and then redeployed the function to use the VPC and NAT. I then called some API from that function, but the API logs are showing a completely different address 169.XXX.XX... What am I missing?

## =======
UPDATE

When I hit an external endpoint, I see the correct IP address.
However, if I send a request to another function within the same GCP project, I get:

```
request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For")
[0.0.0.0]
```

This probably makes sense because the traffic is considered internal?

Comment: Maybe its because of this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/understanding-firewalls#allowing_incoming_requests_from_your_services